# How to remove a ca certificate in debian?

Tags: certificates, java, debian

I have added a root ca in my debian machine by using the following commands:

```
mkdir  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom/
mv myserver.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom/
update-ca-certificates
```

This works as intended, the cacert file in `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` (linked from the java installation folder) is correctly updated by the `ca-certificates-java` package.
However when I remove the file, and rerun the update command, it returns "0 certificates removed".

```
> rm myserver.crt
> sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
```

And it is still in the java cacerts file:

```
echo 'changeit' | keytool -list -v -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts | grep 'Owner:'  | grep myserver
```

Using `update-ca-certificates -f` doesn't help.

So how to remove a ca certificate in debian, and make sure it is also deleted in the java key store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `update-ca-certificates`, it appears you need to explicitly list what to remove in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`:

```
# Handle certificates that should be removed.  This is an explicit act
# by prefixing lines in the configuration files with exclamation marks (!).
sed -n -e '/^$/d' -e 's/^!//p' "$CERTSCONF" | while read crt
do
  remove "$CERTSDIR/$crt"
done
```

In other words, leave your cert file under `/usr/share/ca-certificates`, but put its name in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` prefixed with a `!`.  Just removing the cert doesn't do what you were hoping it would do.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'presumably because the upstream code isn't specifying it' ?
Also, how do you explain that `update-ca-certificates` returns "0 removed" regardless of the java part ?

Comment: @bobif I rewrote the answer after looking at the upstream code - I was focusing on the keystore angle too much before.  New answer explains why `update-ca-certificates` wasn't removing anything.

Comment: Are you sure this is the way ? On the top of the ca-certificates.conf file, it mentions that this file is for /etc/ssl/certs. Moreover, my file myserver.crt is not listed in this file, so I would need to list it there for removal only ? It seems weird. I'm not saying it wouldn't work, just that I have doubts whether it's how it's intended to be used. I can't find any documentation stating how to remove a crt that was added in /usr/share/ca-certificates.

Comment: I believe `update-ca-certificates` will kick off `ca-certificates-java` because of the file `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore` which is dropped by the `ca-certificates-java` package.  If it doesn't work, you'll need to manually remove it from the truststore with `keytool -cacerts -storepass changeit -delete -alias debian:myserver.pem`